# How do I turn a modal image's caption into a link?

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I am working on an image gallery website, and I thought that having modal images would be a nice addition. With the help of w3schools' guide and some other sources I managed to create working modal images for my specifications. However, I also wanted the second half of the caption within a modal to work as a link to another page if clicked, but I can't get it to work.

The JavaScript from w3schools adds the caption based on the text within the `alt` attribute of the image in question. However, since it's already an attribute, I cannot wrap the second half of the caption in an `<a href=""></a>`, or it all stops working.

Here is an example of how the code for the modal images and their captions are working on my site so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modal Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
<style>
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.gallery img{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery img:hover{
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal{
    display: none;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#caption{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*background-color:#ffffff;*/
}
.close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus{
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The Gallery -->
    <div class="gallery">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="Test Caption - Image 1">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500" alt="Test Caption - Image 2">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400" alt="Test Caption - Image 3">
    </div>  
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImg");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){    
        img[i].onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
    }
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function(){ 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Though I dabble in HTML and CSS, I must admit I am still very green with JavaScript and I simply cannot figure this one out. I am wondering if what I am seeking is possible using w3's method for captions, or if I should look for another approach to adding captions to my modal images.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use the caption div as the caption, instead of the image's alt as you did it. That way, you could then make the caption a link with the usual a-Tag. (This is most likely not the only way but the way I see it it's the easiest)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modal Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
<style>
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.gallery img{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery img:hover{
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal{
    display: none;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#caption{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*background-color:#ffffff;*/
}
.close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus{
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
        <div id="caption">Your Caption <a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The Gallery -->
    <div class="gallery">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="Test Caption - Image 1">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500" alt="Test Caption - Image 2">
        <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400" alt="Test Caption - Image 3">
    </div>  
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImg");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){    
        img[i].onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        }
    }
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function(){ 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

> However, I also wanted the second half of the caption within a modal
> to work as a link to another page if clicked, but I can't get it to
> work

I am not 100% what you mean by "Second half", but I have just split up the caption into text and link now, so you can edit it however you want.